Concatenate large matrices leads to memory error
I have two large sparse matrices which I want to concatenate, I am using the following function.
all_data = sparse.vstack([train_data_pt_a, train_data_pt_b])

I can load the two matrices without any issue, however, when the vstack happens, the memory usage spikes and the program terminates (my jupyter notebook states "kernel died")
A solution would be to iterate train_data_pt_b by chunks, append them at the bottom of train_data_pt_a and hope that the garbage collection does its job. Is there any better way ? Or a builtin function for this kind of operations ?
The shape of train_data_pt_a is (318000, 43089) and the percentage of non zero elements is around 7%.
train_data_pt_b has 2 times more rows and a similar non zero percentage.

What type of sparse matrices do you have?  csr?

@DanielF yes they are csr matrices

sparse.vstack converts the matrices to coo format, and makes a new coo matrix by joining the row, col, data arrays appropriately. What's the shape and nnz for your matrices?  It would be nice to know what stage of the process gave the error.

@hpaulj thanks, I edited the question with the infos needed

I can imagine making a new csr by appending the intptr, indices and data arrays  directly. But I don't know if that will help with memory use.

@hpaulj looking into the backend of sparse.vstack, that seems to be what it's doing.  Unless something is failing and making it fall back to dense matrices.

So the new matrix will be ((3*318000, 43089) and 0.07*...*43089 nonzero elements.

So that's 2.87Gb nonzero elements. and 8.6*8 Gb for coo storage, 70 Gb!

@hpaulj so the issue is the COO format ? When the two CSR matrices are in memory, the usage is not that big

I was going to calculate the final csr memory use, but copying between here and the calculator got too tedious.

I am using np.float32 for the data, I guess I can even lower it to float16 without harming the following treatments

But it will need the full 8 bytes for the index arrays.

@hpaulj I just experimented with code that directly constructs indptr, indices, and data from the two input CSR matrices. This did not give any memory usage improvements. While profiling, I discovered that SciPy already implements a fast path for stacking CSR by rows, which does not go through COO. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/561376ca661549f16ddfa6cf4bc78878a7b78a1f/scipy/sparse/_construct.py#L589

You will have to allocate a third set of CSR index/data arrays to hold your new concatenated sparse matrix. If you don't have the memory, your best bet is to write the existing data to disk, free the memory that it's using, allocate the appropriate sized arrays to store the concatenated array, and then read into those new arrays from the files you've written.
